# InputConnection getExtractedText() method behaves differently in native email client apps then in other TextViews

Tags: android, text-extraction, android-input-method

I am currently working on a `Keyboard` ,so basically I'm implementing an `InputMethodService`. The problem I'm facing is this:

The following method:

```
ExtractedText extracted = connection.getExtractedText(new ExtractedTextRequest(), 0);
```

returns a proper `ExtractedText` object on most of the fields except the Text field in the native email client apps on most of the phone models (LG G2, Samsung Galaxy 4, HTC One X were tested). in those fields a `Null` is returned.

I'm guessing that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141118/android-in-browser-edit-text-behavior) is related to the problem I see, but the weird thing is that I see this problem on KitKat as well. So the question is has someone written a `InputMethodService` that would solve this issue?