# getTextBeforeCursor and getExtractedText don't work in Android Marshmallow when using popup menu

Tags: android

I used to use this `getExtractedText` to get all the text from EditText via `InputConnection`, an example:

```
String allText = "";
ExtractedText extractedText = inputConnection.getExtractedText(new ExtractedTextRequest(), 0);
allText = (String)extractedText.text;
```

This example is working fine before Android Marshmallow, now in Marshmallow starting from version 6 to 6.0.1, I've got reports that don't work.

Seems `getExtractedText` returns null.

I used this too to try, but no luck from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25488481/2813238):

```
inputConnection.getTextBeforeCursor(9999, 0).toString();
```

This returns empty text.

Any solution around?

---

**EDIT**

After digging more deeply with this issue, it's because I'm using [popup menu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) which is showing from soft keyboard. When I click on an item from the menu to edit text from EditText, it seems the focus has been lost or something like that and none of methods from getCurrentInputConnection work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd solved this problem, by using `postDelayed` and make sure the popup menu is hidden, and then doing my action to the `EditText` :)

---

Details about how to use postDelayed, [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).